# Solr CursorMark pagination with GroupResult

Tags: solr, pagination, fieldcollapsing

Is there any work around for using CursorMark with Grouped results? When I try it I get the error msg "Can not use Grouping with cursorMark".

I was initially paginating over my documents with start/row but I update my documents between requests, so the order is not reliable anymore.

Then I saw this solution for using cursorMark, but my query needs to be grouped.

Only solution I see now is to query all the IDs I need with grouping and store them in an array on my application, than I could iterate over the array to paginate. But what if this array has 1 million entries, or more? It should be a way to safely paginate with grouping.

Any ideas?

Comment: Had you come across any solution for this?